# Is it dangerous to have a dual boot Macos / Apricity?

Tags: linux, macos, partitioning, multi-boot, arch-linux

I have a Mac and I would like to know : Is it dangerous to split my Disk to have a Macos/Apricity dual boot ?

Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

When setting up dual boot there are opportunities to make mistakes when partitioning your disk that could cause you to lose all of your data. If you have a full, working backup this might not worry you. There are several guides you could follow to avoid mistakes ([example](http://zanshin.net/2015/02/05/how-to-dual-boot-mac-os-x-and-arch-linux-on-a-macbook-pro/)).

Beyond setting up the dual boot, there's nothing inherently dangerous about dual booting. Often macOS and Linux won't be able to read each other's partitions, so the two systems will be completely isolated from each other.